# Teamviewer:Cannot connect to a remote PC in other country?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-desktop, connection, teamviewer

I(using windows machine) have been using Teamviewer recently. I had to help a friend who lives in Italy, so I told him to install Teamviewer for Ubuntu on his laptop.He did everything and told me his client ID so that I could connect to him , but after I press the start session button the Teamviwer software says "Could not establish a connection. Reason unknown." I have used teamviewer to connect to my own mobile and friend's PCs in my own country and it works perfectly.Also my friend in Italy can connect to my PC using the teamviewer software. What are the reasons for thhis issue and possible workarounds ?

Comment: Could be his network blocking it. Can you have him try and connect to you and see if it lets him. Have him make sure the connection is in the green.

Comment: Are you both using the same version of TeamViewer?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Yes he can connect to me I mentioned it in the question already, also he has that green light in the lower part of software window saying ready for connection

Comment: @DavidPostill We both downloaded it recently, I downloaded for windows and he did it for linux, so I think we have the same version but does it matter?

Comment: Yes, it matters.

Comment: ok I will ask him